# Is there a single MSBuild and TFSBuild variable that will point to where the binaries are?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Is there there a property that can be used in either a Visual Studio build or a TFS build that will always point to where the binaries are?

Meaning that when I build in Visual Studio it will point to **C:\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Release** and in a TFS Build it will point to **C:\Build\Path\MySoution\Binaries**

And if there is not one, why not?  This seems like a common, basic need/feature.

Answer (score 8):

There is an `$OutDir` property, which you can use in things like post-build events.

In a VS2010 build, it will be a relative path from the current project to the binaries, so it will be "bin\Debug\" for example. (The full path to the output is $TargetDir, which is $(ProjectDir)\$(Outdir)).

$OutDir is overriden during TFS builds to point to the path where it puts your binaries:

```
 <OutDir Condition=" '%(ConfigurationToBuild.PlatformToBuild)' != 'Any CPU' ">$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.PlatformToBuild)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)\</OutDir>
 <OutDir Condition=" '%(ConfigurationToBuild.PlatformToBuild)' == 'Any CPU' ">$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)\</OutDir>
```

EDIT:

To get a full path  in either case, one option you could use is something like this:

```
IF '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' (
  COPY SomeFile $(TargetDir)$(OutDir)
) ELSE (
  COPY SomeFile $(OutDir)
)
```

Comment: But outdir is relative.  I would really like a full path.  If you have projects in sub directories in your solution then a relative path becomes difficult to use.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where you need to use this property so it's hard to give you a better answer; in a post-build event, for example, the property will be relative to whatever project is running. I'll update my answer with a way to get a full path in either case.