# TFS 2013 build - Files copied using Post Build Event are not found

Tags: tfs, msbuild, auto-build

This is a winform application.
All dlls, exe and some other extension files are copied to the StartupProject\bin through the post build events(VS post-build).

On TFS Server, the project has 2 subfolders: bin and src.(bin contains required dlls, but other extensions are missing -.png, .dat, .xslx).

On the server, the post build copied files appear under the StartupProject\bin, but they are not copied to TFSFolder\bin.
How can I force copy all the StartupProj/bin to the TFSFolder\bin?

Comment: You mean a Visual Studio .csproj event or a TFS build script?

Comment: Visual Studio build event

Answer (score 0):

Team Build use a different directory layouts from Visual Studio builds. All Binaries go in a single folder for any project built, so references are automatically solved and it is easy to copy the DLL to the final Drop folder.

You should use `$(OutDir)` MSBuild variable to properly reference the binaries directory in VS and TFS builds. See [Is there a single MSBuild and TFSBuild variable that will point to where the binaries are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133375/is-there-a-single-msbuild-and-tfsbuild-variable-that-will-point-to-where-the-bin/9133461) for some details.

If you need to use different scripts for desktop (VS) and server (TFS) builds, use the `$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)` variable as explained in [TFS 2010 Build Automation and post-build event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068884/tfs-2010-build-automation-and-post-build-event/6137142#6137142).

Comment: The $(OutDir) solution seems to be working. However, I need to copy the files to both $(OutDir) and StartupProj. Can I do this in one step?(instead of copying to OutDir and then StartupProj?)